# JS PHP Ajax Call don´t work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

im programming a Single Page Application. Now im struggling with Ajax. I have two files,
bhart.js and RespSelArt.php

But my Ajax Call dont want to work.
Im at the point, i only want to display "worked". Now here are 2 Snippets from my Code:

bhart.js

```
    AjaxArtSel = function () {
    alert("2");

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

            document.getElementById("#bhart-SelArt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","AjaxText.php?art=2",true);
    xmlhttp.send();     
}
```

and the AjaxText.php

Before this really easy test I tried it with jquery

bhart.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "AjaxText.php",
    data: "art="+document.getElementById("txtSearchInput").value,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But nothing seems to work. I use jquery 1.11.1 min and the webserver is a IIS8, i tested if php Files get interpreted correcly, and they do. I tried to change $.ajax to $.get and i tried to change it to $.post but nothing works. I give the $.ajax function a datatype no changes. I can´t see why it´s not working :(

Comment: Open Chrome or Firefox, Ctrl+Shift+J , click Console and see what it is doing.

Comment: Is your element's ID literally `id="#bhart-SelArt"`? (The # is for jQuery only)

Comment: open firebug and call this ajax to your script step by step, see where and what is wrong with your call. Also you can use $("#txtSearchInput").val() .

Answer (score 0):

You can have number of problems:

1. PHP doesn't work on your IIS correctly
2. txtSearchInput does not exist therefore it fails
3. AjaxText.php does not return any value or does not exist

Check this code, it is tested and it works perfectly:

AjaxTest.php

```
<?php
echo "it's alive!";
?>
```

and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "AjaxText.php",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});

</script>
<head>

<title>Simple Ajax Test</title>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```